# I'm designing a button from a div, but I want other buttons beside it, so I used inline, however this completely skewed the formatting:

Tags: html, css

Visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/USy5L/

CSS:

```
.upload {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;

    background: #fffbed;
    border: 1px solid #efdec4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(236, 229, 199, 0.3), inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(236, 229, 199, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(236, 229, 199, 0.3), inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(236, 229, 199, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(236, 229, 199, 0.3), inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(236, 229, 199, 0.5);
}

input[type="button"] {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;

    border: 1px solid #4b2218;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    background: #a35a47; /* Old browsers */
}

.filename {
    margin: 14px 0 0 14px;

    color: #bf9e7b;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="upload">
    <input type="button" value="Browse">
    <span class="filename">No file selected</span>
</div>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It works perfectly as intended if I use display:block, however as I need another button on the same line I need it to be inline.

Using the inspector, it shows up with no width and just assumes the width of the parent div. However, I set its width. Does width not get set with an inline element?

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 1):

Try `inline-block` instead of simply `inline`. Or float the elements (floated elements are implicitly displayed as `block`.)

As you have found out, setting the width of an inline element will have no effect.